# Turning @Html.Action into an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is rendering 3 Jquery Tabs showing results from a database

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Obituaries</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Naturalizations</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Censuses</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
@Html.Action("Search", "Obituary", new RouteValueDictionary() { { 
"parameters", Model } })
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">      
  @Html.Action("Search", "Naturalization", new RouteValueDictionary() { { 
"parameters", Model } })
</div>

 <div id="tabs-3">
  @Html.Action("Search", "Census", new RouteValueDictionary() { { 
"parameters", Model } })
</div>
</div>
```

Currently the page is slow to render the tabs, especially with a larger data set, you will see all of the information on the screen for 2-3 seconds before the Jquery script executes to turn the divs into tabs.

I am working on converting my @Html.Action method into an Ajax call, however, I am stumped as how to properly pass my Model to the controller, like I do in my @Html.Action method.

Here is what I have so far....

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '@Html.Url("Search", "Naturalization")',
     dataType: "html",
     data: {//not sure how to pass Model here????  },

     success: function (content) {
        $("#tabs-2").html(content);
     },
     error: function (e) { }
  });
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: You want to pass the entire model to the child actions ? Can't you pass some sort of minimal data and build the model you want in those action methods ?

Comment: Even if you do it correctly - what would be the point - it will be even slower than you current implementation

Comment: @StephenMuecke What would be the best way to speed this up then? Just an ajax call to the DB without calling a controller method at all?

Comment: You cannot make a database call without calling a controller method.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant sending parameters to your controller's method then you could just pass in an object in the Url of the ajax call.

example: /Search/Naturalization?param1=value1&param2=value2.

In your case using Razor, I am not sure but I think you could do:

@Html.Url("Search", "Naturalization", new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 })

Comment: Yes I am sorry for the ambiguity, I do mean passing parameters to my controllers method

Comment: @rajaha if my answer worked for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: I don't think it is meant to be passed in the URL call, I believe it should be passed in the "Data" field as I am trying to do.

Comment: Your AJAX call seems to be doing a GET request. And GET request should not have a model if you are coding using best practices. If you can change the request model to POST then your model will go in the data field in the ajax properties. In order to receive the model on your controller, you need to make sure your ajax is sending a json of your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the parameter as a serialize, but the following will be right approach to do this

Change Main Page modal as below:

```
Public class MainModel{
public subModel1 subModel1List{get;set;}
public subModel1 subModel2List{get;set;}
public subModel1 subModel3List{get;set;}
}
```

---

Main.cshtml page as

```
@using model.MainModel

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Obituaries</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Naturalizations</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Censuses</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
@Html.Partial("PartialPageName1",subModel1)
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">      
@Html.Partial("PartialPageName2",subModel2)
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
 @Html.Partial("PartialPageName3",subModel3)
</div>
</div>

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javqascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//Event that called when you tab data is being rendered, or beofre render use show.bs.tab
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { 
 var newTab = e.target // newly activated tab
 var previousTab = e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
var url = newTab == "tabs-1" ? "PathToPartialPage1ControllerMethod"
                             : "tabs-2" ?  "PathToPartialPage2ControllerMethod" 
                                        :  "PathToPartialPage3ControllerMethod";
var parameter = "tabs-1" ? "{"parameter1" : "XYZ"}"
                             : "tabs-2" ?  "{"parameter2" : "XYZ"}" 
                                        :  "{"parameter3" : "XYZ"}";

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: "html",
     data: parameter ,

     success: function data{

        $("#" + newTab ).html();
     },
     error: function (e) { }
  });

})

});
```

}

---

Partial PartialPageName1.cshtml as

```
@using model.MainModel
 <div>@Model.PropertyOfsubModel1</div>

Create all other partial like above
```

---

Now controller to return Main Page as

```
public ActionResult MainPageView(){
return View(new MainModel()); //You can fill some values here if want or required
}
```